# Google interaction with PHP redirection

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I created a website: www.example.com.
Now, I'm looking for a way to create a mobile version of this Website without dropping in Google Charts. I thought about 2 Options:

1. www.example.com will link to a PHP script which will check if it's a mobile device and then it will redirect the user to the specific side.

Example:
Mobile device: www.example.com -> www.example.com/mobile.html
PC device: www.example.com -> www.example.com/pc.html

If I am right, the negative aspect is that the my homepage will be split in 2 different sites in Google Charts. This will lead to a drop for my homepage over all.

My 2nd option would be that the PHP script will not redirect, but instead load the content of the 2 different HTML pages.

Example:
Mobile device: www.example.com -> www.example.com (contet loaded from www.example.com/mobile.html)
PC device: www.excample.com -> www.example.com (contet loaded from www.example.com/pc.html)

The negative aspect would be that I have to create a new RewriteRule in my htaccess each time I want to get the URL changed. I'm also not sure how Google Charts will react when I'm just working with PHP scripts loading the content of  HTML files.

I'm looking for your experience and opinion, which option you would prefer? Is there maybe a even better method? Is this even a good method to solve this? Please give me your advice.

Comment: Google for responsive design. Then use bootstrap and forget about the methods you mentioned. It's just.. no. No one serious does that nowadays.

Comment: _Aside:_ "i have to create a new RewriteRule in my htaccess each time i want to get the URL changed" - well, you'd have a single rule for the entire mobile site, not a separate rule for each URL - if that is what you were implying? (But as already stated, that is not a good idea anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use either of those suggestions, they are bad for multiple reasons like the difficulty you mentioned, maintaining two sites.

You should look into responsive design, there are many frameworks available that abstract the concepts for you but the extreme basics is this:

Old non-responsive site:

```
// CSS
.container {
    margin-left: 300px;
}

// HTML
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

This only looks good at a certain screen size, if you view it on mobile, or on a very large monitor then it doesn't look good. This gets exponentially worse when you start nesting other design elements inside your container which are sized with specific pixel width/heights.

New responsive site:

```
// CSS
.container {
    margin-left: 20%;
}

// HTML
<div class="container">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

If you resize your browser, or view this on mobile then it will always look the same. If you use a percentage then the page will resize depending on your device.

That's the basics, do some research into responsive design and you can do more advanced things like specific layouts for very small screens, e.g mobile

I'd recommend looking into bootstrap which is a great framework for beginners getting into responsive design.

Comment: So, are you suggesting the OP should redo their existing website?

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I'm suggesting. I don't know exactly what the css/html structure of their website is currently. It might be easy enough to change some values in the CSS, responsive design is usually best when it's a focus from the start.

Comment: @user82217 are you suggesting that NOT using responsive design, but different HTML all together is a better solution? OP did ask for suggestions, and this is a good one. Responsive design kills 2 flies with 1 stone in this case.

Comment: @Mjh Not at all. Responsive for the win. I was just clarifying that this approach could potentially require a redesign of the existing desktop site as well, rather than just a separate "add-on" for mobile, which would seem to be how the OP was initially thinking.